# Finding Subarrays of Vowels from a given String

Tags: python, arrays, string, algorithm

You are given a string S, and you have to find all the amazing substrings of S.

Amazing Substring is one that starts with a vowel (a, e, i, o, u, A, E, I, O, U).

**Input**

The only argument given is string S.

**Output**

Return a single integer X mod 10003, here X is number of Amazing Substrings in given string.

**Constraints**

- 1 <= length(S) <= 1e6
- S can have special characters

**Example**

```
Input
    ABEC

Output
    6

Explanation
    Amazing substrings of given string are :
    1. A
    2. AB
    3. ABE
    4. ABEC
    5. E
    6. EC
    here number of substrings are 6 and 6 % 10003 = 6.
```

I have implemented the following algo for the above Problem.

```py
    class Solution:
        # @param A : string
        # @return an integer
        def solve(self, A):
            x = ['a', 'e','i','o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
            y = []
            z = len(A)
            for i in A:
                if i in x:
                    n = A.index(i)
                    m = z
                    while m > n:
                        y.append(A[n:m])
                        m -= 1
            if y:
                return len(y)%10003
            else:
            return 0
```

Above Solution works fine for strings of normal length but not for greater length.

For example,

```
A = "pGpEusuCSWEaPOJmamlFAnIBgAJGtcJaMPFTLfUfkQKXeymydQsdWCTyEFjFgbSmknAmKYFHopWceEyCSumTyAFwhrLqQXbWnXSn"
```

Above *Algo outputs 1630* subarrays but the *expected answer is 1244*.

Please help me improving the above algo. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Focus on the required output: you do not need to find all of those substrings.  All you need is the *quantity* of substrings.

Look again at your short example, `ABEC`.  There are two vowels, `A` and `E`.

- `A` is at location 0.  There are 4 total substrings, ending there and at each following location.
- `E` is at location 2.  There are 2 total substrings, ending there and at each following location.

2+4 => 6

All you need do is to find the position of each vowel, subtract from the string length, and accumulate those differences:

```
A = "pGpEusuCSWEaPOJmamlFAnIBgAJGtcJaMPFTLfUfkQKXeymydQsdWCTyEFjFgbSmknAmKYFHopWceEyCSumTyAFwhrLqQXbWnXSn"

lenA = len(A)
vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"
count = 0

for idx, char in enumerate(A):
    if char in vowel:
       count += lenA - idx

print(count%10003)
```

Output:

```
1244
```

In a single command:

```
print( sum(len(A) - idx if char.lower() in "aeiou" else 0
       for idx, char in enumerate(A)) )
```

Comment: How does it care about the duplicates strings?
aaa => a, aa, aaa, a, aa, a

Comment: @amirbeygi: I'm not clear on what you want to know.  What result did you get, that you do not understand?

Answer (score 3):

When you hit a vowel in a string, all sub-strings that start with this vowel are 'amazing' so you can just count them:

```
def solve(A):
            x = ['a', 'e','i','o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
            ans = 0

            for i in range(len(A)):
                if A[i] in x:
                    ans = (ans + len(A)-i)%10003
            return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking for the index of the element `n = A.index(i)`, you get the index of the first occurrence of the element. By using `enumerate` you can loop through indices and elements simultaneously.

```
def solve(A):
    x = ['a', 'e','i','o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
    y = []
    z = len(A)
    for n,i in enumerate(A):
        if i in x:
            m = z
            while m > n:
                y.append(A[n:m])
                m -= 1
    if y:
        return len(y)%10003
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution is to find all amazing substrings and then count them :

```
string = "pGpEusuCSWEaPOJmamlFAnIBgAJGtcJaMPFTLfUfkQKXeymydQsdWCTyEFjFgbSmknAmKYFHopWceEyCSumTyAFwhrLqQXbWnXSn"

amazing_substring_start = ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']

amazing_substrings = []

for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i] in amazing_substring_start:
        for j in range(len(string[i:])+1):
            amazing_substring = string[i:i+j]
            if amazing_substring!='':
                amazing_substrings += [amazing_substring]

print amazing_substrings,len(amazing_substrings)%10003
```

Answer (score 0):

create a loop to calculate the number of amazing subarrays created by every vowel

```
def Solve(A):
    sumn = 0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] in "aeiouAEIOU":
            sumn += len(A[i:])
    return sumn%10003
```